# Java's Overriding - Can't correctly override a function

Tags: java, overriding

I'm having some troubles with overriding a base class in java 1.7.

My goal is to override the method f(), so that the program will iterate using a different function than the one in the base class.

My problem is that I can't seem to override the function, even though they're named the same, have the same return type, and the same parameters.

[Here's the base file](http://pastebin.com/Gv8sh5Hj)

[And here's the file that's trying to override the base file](http://pastebin.com/K8h4VAii)

Currently the code works, I can set all the initial and ending values, I just can't get the function method in the second file to override the first.

Comment: Please include your code here instead of making us follow the links provided.

Answer (score 4):

You can't override a static function.

Answer (score 3):

This is not overriding (an instance method), this is [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) (a static method).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, static method can't be overridden. Consider making methods non static and using object instance to do calculations.

Something like this will go to `Runge5`.

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
   Runge2 r = new Runge5();
   r.doCalculations();
}
```

`doCalculations()` would include the code that you had in `main()`;

It's, probably not the best design but it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still a little shaky on implementing what your suggesting.

I would just wrap up my main in a new method, doCalculations(), and then override that from inside my runge5 class?

Comment: you can only override `f()` as you intended. doCalculations() could remain the same.